# Create custom field on tfs 2010 work item to contain values from other fields

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm a new TFS Admin and have a request to create a custom field on Bug and Requirement work items that will contain the following data: Work Item Type + id + title.  I can get the field created and the control added to the form.  I just can't figure out how to get the selected values into the field.  I'm trying to use the System.WorkItemType + System.Id + System.Title fields to populate the new field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS natively doesn't support calculated fields like this.  However, you can use a 3rd party tool (or write your own ISubscriber plugin) to accomplish it.

The TFS Aggregator tool might be able to do this for you: http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/

Comment: This looks like a good option.  The requestor has changed their request so now just displaying the System.ID field on the form.